# identify himself with Chinese ways 怎么翻译？

Tags: translation

> He shaved off his hair and beard, wore the dress of a Buddhist monk,
> and identified himself with Chinese ways.

（利玛窦）他剃发割须，身着佛教僧衣，且以中国人的方式来（定位）自己。

这是字译。但是“定位”二字感觉太现代了，不适合上下文的语境。若翻译成“给自己取了一个中文名字”或“使自己看起来像一个中国人”等又感觉似乎与愿意相差太远。

Answer (score 2):

> He shaved off his hair and beard, wore the dress of a Buddhist monk, and **identified himself** with Chinese ways.

My Translation of the English text:

> 他剃发割须，身披僧裝，以中国人之行事方式**自我认同**。

Google Translate result of my translation

> He shaves his hair and beard, wears a monk's robe, and **identifies himself** with the Chinese ways.

**Edit:**

From my comment:

- If he wanted to make himself looked like a Chinese" - 使自己看起来像一个中国人)
- If he saw himself as a Chinese" - 當自己是一个中国人

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the full context, there are a few choices of the words "定位" and "方式":

- He shaved off his hair and beard, wore the dress of a Buddhist monk, and **positioned/aligned/expressed** himself with Chinese ways/**manners**.

Based on the limited text, my understanding is that "He wanted to be seen as a true Chinese person, so in addition to shaving his hair and beard, wearing monk dress, he acted in the way/manner that a normal Chinese person does.

Answer (score 1):

"identified himself with Chinese ways." is ambiguous: did he proactively display Chinese behaviour, or empathetically feel Chinese? I assume the former.

He's a spy??

他剃掉头发和胡须，
He shaved off his hair and beard,
穿着和尚的衣服，
wore the clothes of a Buddhist monk
试图模仿中国人的方式和举止。
and tried to assume Chinese ways and mannerisms.

(But, because of his blonde hair and blue eyes, people didn't believe he was Chinese, caught, captured and executed him. 太糟糕了007！)

Comment: Not a spy, and definitely not executed. Is this supposed to be a "joke"??

Comment: it sounds like a joke

Comment: He's a famous missionary.

Comment: Inspired by your translation, I decide to use "使自己看起来完全像一个中国人"

Comment: Good translation, I like it! He was not a missionary, he was Jesuit spy! The Chinese were right to confine the foreigners to Macao!

Comment: @shenkwen "Make oneself looked like something" (使自己看起来像一个中国人) is different from "See oneself as something" (當自己是一个中国人). See my edition